# adding spell check to text area?

Tags: apache-flex, dictionary, spell-checking

i am creating an AIR app and i need any idea how to do spell check on text area in flex actionscript. also any idea how to bind a dictionary with text area is also useful

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Squiggly](http://blogs.adobe.com/koestler/tag/squiggly) is a free availavble API for AS3 Apps will do all you needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Squiggly](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/squiggly/) is the best choice for you. It allows both check spelling and display/fix spelling problems.

Answer (score 0):

Using Squiggly you can achieve this. Flow the setup mentioned there and use below code:

In the application file write below function on applicationComplete event

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"       applicationComplete="init()">

  public function init():void
        {
            var resourceTable:ResourceTable = new ResourceTable();
            resourceTable.setResource("en_US", {rule:"data/en_US.aff", dict:"data/en_US.dic"});
            SpellingConfiguration.resourceTable = resourceTable;
        }
```

This is for English language, similarly you can register other language too.

For which input control (TextInput/ TextArea) you want this spell check functionality write the below mentioned code:

```
 <mx:TextInput id="txtInput" width="100%" creationComplete="SpellUI.enableSpelling(txt, 'en_US');"/>
```

All done have fun :)
Hope this will help.

-S